# Rails 7 - React application not loading assets from subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

I recently migrated a React-Rails application from rails 6 to 7. Since Webpacker was discontinued, I tried configuring Webpack on the javascript side.

The rails application is configured to load from a subdirectory. However, the assets of the application are not present in the path with the subdirectory, causing the application to fail to load properly.

For example, the application tries to load the assets from
`http://localhost:3000/myapp/assets/application.js` but the assets are present in `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js`

How do I configure the assets so that it loads from the subdirectory?

I have tried several solutions but none seem to work. Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sprocket with rails 7 importmap (combined) I think steps below can help you

1. create manifest file inside app/assets/config/manifest.js and add this content below

```js
   //= link_tree ../../myapp/assets .js
```

- this line above to call /myapp/assets
- first ../ will move backward from app/assets/config/ to app/assets/
- you probably need to manage relative path below from the location of manifest.js

2. additional notes, since I also want to use rails 7 javascript with their importmap
   I would like to suggest two additional steps below

- rename file name myapp/assets/application.js to other for example myapp/assets/application_webpack.js
- open open file app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and add your javascript_include_tag

```html
  <head>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %> 

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application_webpack", "data-turbo-track" => true %> 
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with my case is I am trying to load the application in a subdirectory, and the assets are not being loaded from that subdirectory (but it loads perfectly when I don't load the app in the subdirectory).
Do you have any additional insights or suggestions that could help me solve this issue?